# Django ORM: Reverse relation query multiple model from single models

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I am in trouble querying reverse relation, I learned a lot about `select_related` and `prefetch_related`, yet I failed to achieve this.

At first see my models:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

class Person(models.Model):
    alias = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Appointment(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="patient_for_appointment", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Sales(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="customer_for_sales", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.FloatField()

class Prescription(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="Patient_for_prescription", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I am trying to filter `Person` Model to check if the person has any `prescription`, `sales`, and `appointment` I want to get these all with single query like the person. will filter it with a person `alias` (primary key)

I can filter it with separate query like

```
patient_alias = '53fsdfsdf-fdsfds-df-fdf'
queryset = Appointment.objects.filter(
     patient__alias=patient_alias
 )
```

But I don't want this, coz, it has a performance issue. I don't want this with separate query.

I want to query only `Person` model to check if a person has Appointment, prescription or Sales

like `Person.objects.filter(alias='a person alias)`

Can anyone please help me to achieve this?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can select all `Person`s, except the ones that hav no `Appointment`, nor a `Sales` or `Prescription` with:

```
Person.objects.exclude(
    patient_for_appointment=None,
    customer_for_sales=None,
    Patient_for_prescription=None
)
```

This will yield a query that looks like:

```
SELECT person.alias, person.name
FROM person
WHERE NOT (
    person.alias IN (
        SELECT U0.alias
        FROM person U0
        LEFT OUTER JOIN prescription U1 ON U0.alias = U1.patient_id
        WHERE U1.id IS NULL
    )
    AND person.alias IN (
        SELECT U0.alias
        FROM person U0
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sales U1 ON U0.alias = U1.customer_id
        WHERE U1.id IS NULL AND U0.alias = person.alias
    )
    AND person.alias IN (
        SELECT U0.alias
        FROM person U0
        LEFT OUTER JOIN appointment U1
        ON U0.alias = U1.patient_id
        WHERE U1.id IS NULL AND U0.alias = person.alias
    )
)
```

Or we can make a union, like:

```
Person.objects.filter(
    patient_for_appointment__isnull=False
).union(
    Person.objects.filter(customer_for_sales__isnull=False),
    Person.objects.filter(Patient_for_prescription__isnull=False)
)
```

This will result in a query that looks like:

```
(
    SELECT person.alias, person.name
    FROM person
    INNER JOIN appointment ON person.alias = appointment.patient_id
    WHERE appointment.id IS NOT NULL
) UNION (
    SELECT person.alias, person.name FROM person
    INNER JOIN sales ON person.alias = sales.customer_id
    WHERE sales.id IS NOT NULL
) UNION (
    SELECT person.alias, person.name
    FROM person
    INNER JOIN prescription ON person.alias = prescription.patient_id
    WHERE prescription.id IS NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: No, this is not proper solution. I heared of people querying with select related, prefetch realted of django ORM. Your solution is not ok

Comment: Remove your solution, it is completely bad practice!

Comment: @mamuncode: `prefetch_related` does not do anything at all for filter! It only adds *extra* queries (!) to then do a JOIN at the Python side. So that would only *increase* the load.

Comment: @dudd: then what is bad about the solution? :)

Comment: @mamuncode: take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related  It clearly states "*prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects,*". So here you actually will do what, in your question text, you wanted to avoid: making **multiple** roundtrips to the database :P

Comment: Yes, i want to avoid multiple roundtrips in the database. Your given solution are not ok, coz, Your query will only show one result. I need four result together in just single query

Comment: @mamuncode: exactly what would the four results be here? :)

Comment: If this Person has Appointments, Prescription, Sales etc. If no appointment, it should return None, and if Appointment exist, it should return Appontment detail  like this

Comment: @mamuncode: well you cann add extra `.prefetch_related(..)` parts, like `Person.objects.filter(
    patient_for_appointment__isnull=False
).union(
    Person.objects.filter(customer_for_sales__isnull=False),
    Person.objects.filter(Patient_for_prescription__isnull=False)
).prefetch_related('patient_for_appointment', 'patient_for_prescription', 'customer_for_sales')`. But then you will make extra queries. But that is not bad here, in fact querying a 1-to-many relation and fetching it in one query could result in the network getting congested with duplicates.

Comment: So then you get a queryset of `Person`s that already have an `Appointment`/`Sales`/`Prescription`, and where these are fetched. By doing that in one query, you would create a table that is the result of three (!) joins, so if your tables are large, it could easily result in millions of (duplicated) rows.

Comment: Yes, exactly it is what i want

Comment: Thanks for your time for nice thinking